# Srapy startproject error - Python 3 - BashOnUbuntuOnWindows

Tags: python, scrapy, bash-on-windows

I try to use Scrapy for the first time in a Bash On Ubuntu On Windows 10 and get this error when i start a new project:

```
(myvenv) mothinx@DESKTOP-4M9JDPL:~/laplanetebleue$ scrapy startproject laplanetebleue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 128, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/commands/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: /home/mothinx/laplanetebleue/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

pip freeze:

```
asn1crypto==0.22.0
attrs==17.2.0
Automat==0.6.0
cffi==1.11.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.0.3
cssselect==1.0.1
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.6
incremental==17.5.0
lxml==4.0.0
parsel==1.2.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyasn1==0.3.5
pyasn1-modules==0.1.4
pycparser==2.18
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pyOpenSSL==17.3.0
queuelib==1.4.2
Scrapy==1.4.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
Twisted==17.5.0
w3lib==1.18.0
zope.interface==4.4.2
```

Is it a problem with crypto or pyOpenSSL ? Pretty new here in python, can someone decrypt me the Traceback ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150433/installing-scrapy-python-and-easy-install-on-windows-7/45963674#45963674

Comment: Just search the error message (*cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument*) on Google. First two links I obtained gave answer to the problem.

Comment: [Python3.4 error - Cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136040/python3-4-error-cannot-enable-executable-stack-as-shared-object-requires-inva) explains it

Comment: In conclusion, there is some bricks in BashOnWindowsOnLinux wich are not yet implemented. Thank you guys. I will return on my Windows environment so :'(