# Ada: error while loading shared libraries: libgnatprj

Tags: compilation, libraries, ada, gnat

I am trying to compile my ada program on ubuntu on windows.

I am running

> gnatmake sieve.adb

And getting the following output

> /usr//bin/gnatbind: error while loading shared libraries: libgnatprj.so.4.9: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
>
> gnatmake: *** bind failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which Gnat are you using and how did you install it? Is it possible you have two incompatible versions? This looks like an installation problem.

Comment: Might be an instance of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136040/python3-4-error-cannot-enable-executable-stack-as-shared-object-requires-inva/39223317)